# How to send generated password to email while registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I know this question may be duplicated but i didn't find an answer. 
I'm registering a user (not laravel registration) and I've made a generated password and entered an email. I want to send that password to that email right after clicking on save button. Any help please?

Comment: Don't do this.  Not only should you never send a password over email, and not only should you never display a user's password at all, you should never *be able* to do these things.  If you are storing user passwords in any retrievable format, whether plain text or even encrypted, you're doing it wrong.  User passwords should be obscured behind a 1-way hash and should never be retrievable in their original form.  Not even by you as the system admin.

Comment: So how can the admin give the password to the user?

Comment: You mentioned "not laravel registration", so what registration is it?  Something you wrote?  If that's the case then you can change it however you need to.  In this case, why generate a password at all?  Why not let the user set their password when they register?  Failing that, maybe don't give the user the generated password at all but instead initiate whatever your process is for a user to reset a forgotten password, since the overall process is the same.

Comment: okay my bad , I had to explain. I'm working on a project where the admin enters workers informations to database. And these workers will need password to use it in the mobile app I've made too, hope its all clear now. You can say that mobile accounts are made from web. They only connect from mobile. Its for a center ..

Comment: If you feel that you *absolutely must* send the user their initial password, then you would do it with the generated value before you lose that value.  You should *not* be able to read the password from the database.  Ever.  But honestly I really recommend starting the user with an unknown password and a link they can click to reset a forgotten password, the same exact process they'd use if they click on a "forgot password" link.

Comment: Exactly! I want to send this "starter" password in email and then change it.. Its not even shown for the admin.

Comment: send a 'starter' link instead, and let the user set their own password.

Comment: @nihel: Again, if you feel you *must* do this for just the initial password, then I guess go ahead and do this.  As long as it's *never possible* to do it again.  (And it's still recommended *not* to do this and to send the user a password reset link instead.)  But if you *really want* to do this your way, then I guess go ahead.  At that point, what's the question?  What isn't working?

Comment: @David well, I just don't know how to do it. :/

Comment: @nihel: How to send an email in PHP?  A Google search for something like "how to send an email in PHP" can get you started.  If you encounter a specific problem such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple way to send an email:

```
public function sendEmail(\StdClass $data){
    Mail::send('email.plain_text', [ //view page
        'message_txt' => $data->message //Data for the page
    ], function ($message) use ($data){ 
        $message->from('developer@gmail.com', 'Gmail');
        $message->subject($data->subject);
        $message->to($data->email);
    });
}
```